# Strictness of the Principal Argument

Tags: complex-numbers

Why is $-\pi$ not included in the principal argument, but $\pi$ is?

Comment: Convention. ${}$

Comment: The definition is by choice. We could have done the reverse also, without any loss of generality, but this is the convention. However, if you want to ask why both are not included simultaneously, then the principal argument will not be unique for negative real numbers.

Comment: @Wojowu : If one had to decide at the time of the creation of the Earth whether everyone should drive on the left side of the road or the right, one might toss a coin and expect that either result would serve equally well. In that case it is ONLY convention. But I suspect something else is involved here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If there really is some kind of intrinsic reason for choosing $\pi$ over $-\pi$, I would be very much interested to hear it.

Comment: @Wojowu : There is a reasonable presumption against minus signs. The added typographical complexity is not only typographical; it involves a concept that was not introduced until mathematics had been done for many centuries. And even merely typographical complexity should be avoided when it serves no purpose.